# Is there a way around low ram application limit?

Tags: android, memory, libraries

I have application which in one method needs to load 2 large bitmaps, mask bitmap and perform masking process. It works fine until device has 16 MB ram limit.

My question is - ***are there any libraries that will allow using internal storage on specific method in case of overflow on heap memory***?

Answer (score 0):

If the bitmaps are used for display on the screen try downsizing them on decode.
[BitmapFactory.Options.SampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

If that is not an option you can try sacrificing some performance with

[BitmapFactory.Options.inPurgeable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPurgeable) = true